# Como verificar novos campos inseridos em uma tabela mysql em tempo real?

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

No meu trabalho tem uma banco de dados onde um sistema de catracas insere novos campos na tabela e a aplicação NodeJS precisa verificar quando tem campos novos inseridos.

Qual é a melhor forma de monitorar uma tabela em tempo real?

Pesquisei e vi que criar um *trigger* não seria um boa opção, teria que usar um [socket.io](http://socket.io/) para dar um *watch* em tempo real na tabela?

Comment: Você poderia adicionar o código que você tentou?

Comment: E por **campos** você refere-se a campos da tabela mesmo ou registros da mesma? Campo está relacionado à coluna na tabela, espaço para armazenar dados, já registro é o dado armazenado em si.

Comment: Eu ainda não fiz nenhum código, sou novo no node js e estou em duvida, tipo teria que ser um loop que fica verificando se tem novos campos na tabela.

Comment: Como é o código de _"um sistema de catracas insere novos campos na tabela"_? não é possivel que esse código partilhe informação com o código que verifica campos inseridos?